# Spatial geometry columns vs float/decimal columns in storing longitude/lattitude

Tags: postgresql, maps, gis, postgis

I need to store and give out long/lat coordinates and display on google maps. I would need to store points, lines, and polygons. Then add metadata on them to for generating info.

Currently looking into postgis, and it seems a fair bit to absorb. Now I'm wondering if I need to delve into it.

Is it advisable to use a spatial database for the said purpose? or using float/decimal columns for long/lat is fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently looking into postgis, and it seems a fair bit to absorb. Now I'm wondering if I need to delve into it. Is it advisable to use a spatial database for the said purpose? or using float/decimal columns for long/lat is fine?

It is a lot to absorb. Storing as a float/decimal gets you nothing. Nothing at all. Spatial functions require spatial types. You gotta learn it. You don't have to learn all of it, but you have to learn it. And, it's not too hard to get started.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id,geom)
AS
  VALUES ( 1, ST_MakePoint(long,lat)::geography );
```

Etc.

I highly suggest [PostGIS in Action 2nd Edition](https://www.manning.com/books/postgis-in-action-second-edition)

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you need is store and give out, then float/decimal columns would be more than enough. However, if you are querying for spatial relations (whether a point is located within a polygon, whether polygons intersect etc.), you'd better to use either PostGIS or, for instance, MySQL extensions for spatial data.